# Issues with a circular table reference MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

Not really a DBA, but was tasked with designing a couple new tables for a new feature in a web app. DB is MySQL, using NHibernate as ORM (though that's probably irrelevant to the question).

I'm going to be modelling various, "scenarios" which represent different variations of several designs in the app. Aside from the first scenario & "unstarted" scenarios, each scenario will have a parent scenario they're building from. As a result, will end up with a sort of "no-loop / no-merge" tree structure as scenarios are branched from one another.

```
CREATE TABLE `scenarios` (
  `ScenarioID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DesignID` INT DEFAULT NULL,
  `ScenarioTreeID` INT NOT NULL,
  `ParentScenarioID` INT DEFAULT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
```

In addition to the scenarios themselves, there's information that's best related to the entire "Tree" of scenarios (e.g. what structure are the scenarios related to, etc). I've tried to factor this data out into another table called `scenariotree` and reference it from `scenarios` via `ScenarioTreeID`. The issue I ran into was, from a querying perspective, that it'd be important to know what the "root scenario" is when I query the tree (I can't just go `WHERE ParentScenarioID is NULL` as that includes "unstarted" scenarios). So I tried to set up the table as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `scenariotree` (
  `ScenarioTreeID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `StructureID` INT NOT NULL,
  `RootScenario` INT DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
```

But then I couldn't create either table due to the circular foreign key references. I realise I can create the tables first & then add the foreign keys in (or just turn FK checks off & then on again when I'm finished), but should I be doing this? Poking around online I'm finding conflicting opinions. Basically what I want to ask is:

*"Is this acceptable schema design, or am I going to run into issues down the road? If so, what issues am I likely to have & how might I restructure these tables to avoid them?"*

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to have circular references. They are less common than not have cycles, but they are legitimate to model some data structures.

They do require some special handling, as you discovered. That's okay and it's necessary.

You already identified two ways of handling them:

- `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` temporarily while you insert the mutually-depended data. One problem with this is that some people forget to re-enable the checks, and then some weeks later discover that their data is full of references that point to non-existing data.
- Create the table first, then use ALTER TABLE to add the foreign keys after you populate the data. The problem here is that if you need to add new rows to existing tables, you'd have to drop the foreign keys and re-add them every time, and this affects all clients, not just your session.

A couple of other options:

- Make one or the other foreign key nullable. When you need to insert mutually-dependent rows in the two tables, insert the one with nullable FK first, and use a NULL. Then insert to the other table. Then UPDATE the first table to assign the non-NULL value it should reference.
- Finally, don't use FOREIGN KEY constraints. You will have columns that reference other columns, but it's sort of on the "honor system" instead of having a RDBMS-enforced constraint. This comes with its own risks of course, because any data that is supposed to be a foreign key has no assurance that it correct. But it gives you total freedom to insert in whatever order you need to. You can use a transaction to make sure inserts to both tables happen together.